# Researcher who reinvented least squares regression? Urban legend?

Tags: regression, least-squares, history, knowledge-discovery

I can't recall where I read about this.

Supposedly, a young researcher (or student?) in the 1970s or 1980s independently rediscovered and published their methodology for ordinary least squares regression, completely ignorant of the fact that OLS regression has been in use for over a century.

Is this true or a statistics "urban legend"?

Comment: Although this is plausible it is scarcely of any interest: people reinvent basic procedures all the time.  Perhaps it is a version of something that actually happened; namely, a failure of a noted statistician to understand the basic implications of regression.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/24649/919 for my brief account of one such circumstance (the story of Horace Secrist).

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the link - I'm always up for a good laugh if the regression article was actually published.