Behaviour of regression toward the mean
I have a dataset for length of right and left foot in 801 people, males and females. This is a teaching dataset without any specific question or peculiarity behind it, as far as I can tell.
Here are the means and covariance matrix, units are cm:
## Means
LengthRightFoot  LengthLeftFoot 
           24.3            24.3 

## Covariance matrix
                LengthRightFoot LengthLeftFoot
LengthRightFoot            6.34           6.08
LengthLeftFoot             6.08           6.31

A regression of left foot on right shows that, contrary to intuition, the slope is slight below 1 and the intercept is above 0 (see below). I believe this is due to the regression toward the mean. So far so good, unless you have a better explanation.
What puzzles me is that the intercept is suspiciously close to 1 (0.99877). Of course, 0.99877 is a number like other, but I wonder if there is a reason for the intercept to be nearly exactly 1. Can you shed any light?

Call:
lm(formula = LengthLeftFoot ~ LengthRightFoot)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-2.254 -0.239 -0.025  0.187  8.823 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      0.99877    0.23741    4.21  2.9e-05 ***
LengthRightFoot  0.95891    0.00973   98.50  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.693 on 799 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.924, Adjusted R-squared:  0.924 
F-statistic: 9.7e+03 on 1 and 799 DF,  p-value: <2e-16


This simulation in R generates a dataset of 50000 observation with covariance matrix similar to the real one. The regression recapitulates the findings above:
mu <- c(24.3, 24.3)
covmat <- structure(c(6.33766534019975, 6.07723639200999, 
    6.07723639200999, 6.3073693196005), dim = c(2L, 2L), 
      dimnames = list(c("LengthRightFoot", 
      "LengthLeftFoot"), c("LengthRightFoot", "LengthLeftFoot")))

sim <- as.data.frame(mvrnorm(n=50000, mu=mu, Sigma=covmat))

Regression on simulated data:
summary(lm(LengthLeftFoot ~ LengthRightFoot, data=sim))
Call:
lm(formula = LengthLeftFoot ~ LengthRightFoot, data = sim)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.9058 -0.4683 -0.0034  0.4622  2.7255 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     1.037961   0.030047   34.55   <2e-16 ***
LengthRightFoot 0.957488   0.001231  777.63   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.6921 on 49998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9236,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9236 
F-statistic: 6.047e+05 on 1 and 49998 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16


Hint: What happens to the intercept when you express all lengths in, say, inches?

How is this regression to mean?

@Harvey Because the variances are essentially equal, obtaining a slope less than $1$ empirically illustrates regression to the mean.  Also, because the means are (exactly) equal and the covariances are positive, obtaining a positive intercept also is evidence of regression to the mean.

Regression to the mean occurs when participants (or experimental units) are selected because some measurement was extreme. this is partly due to chance, which is unlikely to repeat. So when you measure again, the measurement is likely to be less extreme. I dont see how the example in this question is regression to the mean.????

@HarveyMotulsky If it helps, I edited my question with simulated data from a multivariate normal distribution of 50000 observation which recapitulates the original findings.

@HarveyMotulsky In my understanding, regression to the mean does not require selection or experimental design to occur. In this case, a person with an "extreme" right foot (either real or due to measurement error) is not so extreme also in the left foot. This means that the slope is slightly underestimated and the intercept is overestimated because an extreme right foot is not associated to an equally extreme left foot.

@Harvey You appear to be alluding to one popular explanation applying only to certain circumstances (repeated measurements), whereas regression to the mean is a far more general phenomenon.  See, for instance, my (very brief) account at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/24649/919.

This is just a coincidence. Remember that the intercept is the predicted value of the outcome when the predictor is set to 0. What does it mean to have a right foot length of 0cm? Nothing. The line is extrapolating to that point, and it should not be interpreted.
It is worth remembering how the intercept is estimated in simple linear regression.
$$
b_0 = \bar y - \hat b_1 \bar x
$$
In this example, we have that $\bar y \approx \bar x = m$, so we can say
$$
b_0 = (1 - \hat b_1)m
$$
That is, the intercept is a natural consequence of the slope's deviation from 1. It happens to be the case that the product of the deviation from 1 and the mean length is approximately equal to 1, but there is no substantive reason for this to be considered an interesting result. It is a natural consequence of the line being forced to go through the point corresponding to the mean of both predictors and the regression to the mean (maybe better characterized as imperfect correlation or measurement error).

Noah is correct (+1) also see whuber's comment. If you change the unit, the intercept and slope will change.
As to the reason that the slope and intercept are not as close to 0 as you thought they would be, I notice the extremely high maximum of the residual from the regression - much farther from 0 than the lowest.
That's weird. It could be a data entry error, but it could be some sort of deformity, or maybe something else. If you can, I would check out that person. Does your data set have any other info?
You could also try running the regression after removing that observation. And look at a plot of the residuals, too.
NOTE: I removed the sentence interpreting the residual, as it was incorrect. See wbuber's comment for the correct interpretation.

The slope does not change with a change in units (unless you use different units to measure the different feet...).  Your observation about a large residual is good, but  appears to misinterpret it: the fit is not $y=x;$ it is $y = 1 + 0.96x,$ so that the residuals are $y-0.96x-1,$ not $y-x.$  Nevertheless a residual of $8.8$ within a dataset with an estimated residual sd of just $0.7$ still suggests an extraordinary discrepancy.  Regardless, these considerations--although valid--don't provide insight into the original question concerning the closeness of the intercept to $1.$

Yes, well spotted, but the extreme datapoint has virtually no effect. See also my edit to the answer with simulated data.
